# Last in First out Visual basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have a question regarding on stack (counterpart of hash table). Basically I know the push and pop method. However could anyone give me an idea on how to do when dealing when a user inputs a word. All vowels are removed and only inserted are consonants in the listbox.

Trying to research this problem but couldn't find it.

Comment: My mistake, anyway I'm just searching a solution since the basic push and pop is the majority all that I've found.

Comment: actually you are looking for a FIFO(*first in/first out*) which is a [`Queue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Its a Last in, First out. I didn't check at all before posting it.

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense to me, first you ask about a queue (or stack) and then you talk about inserting values into a listbox

Comment: To make everything clear, I'm basically asking if what idea could a push and pop make when filtering the vowels as the user input a words and place in the listbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this. It is intercepting your keystrokes when you type them into the textbox and placing them into your stack, when you hit enter it then process it removing the values and assigning it to your listbox. If this is not what you are asking you will need to be a bit clearer.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim myStack As Stack(Of Char) = New Stack(Of Char)

    Private Sub processStack(value As Stack(Of Char))
        Dim temp As List(Of Char) = New List(Of Char)
        Do While value.Count > 0
            Dim c As Char = value.Pop
            Select Case c
                Case "a"c, "e"c, "i"c, "o"c, "u"c
                Case "A"c, "E"c, "I"c, "O"c, "U"c
                Case Else
                    temp.Add(c)
            End Select
        Loop
        ListBox1.Items.Add(New String(temp.ToArray))
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
        If Not e.KeyChar = vbCr Then
            myStack.Push(e.KeyChar)
        Else
            DirectCast(sender, TextBox).Clear()
            processStack(myStack)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the second part of you question (which seems to have nothing to do with a queue or stack):

```
Dim inputString As String = "Some old harvesters can always have tankards of ale"
Dim vowels As Char() = {"a"c, "e"c, "i"c, "o"c, "u"c}

For Each c As Char In inputString.ToLower()
    If Not vowels.Contains(c) Then
        'display any constanants in the string
        Console.WriteLine(c)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Using push and pop of Stack dealing on vowels?